# Spring REST update parameter value after validation

Tags: java, spring, rest

Is it possible to update a parameter value after constraint validation?

My parameters after validation need to set to Upper case if not. Is there a way to set it at the start along with the parameter constraint validations?

Comment: If the uppercase value is supposed to be used in the business logic, I guess you'd better convert to uppercase before validation. For that custom argument resolver as described in [Binding Domain Objects](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-data-binder) should do just fine.

Comment: thanks yegodm. Thats very helpful